# ¿Como puedo obtener la ip de mi SO (Guest) Windows XP montado en Vmware desde linux por consola?

Tags: linux, bash, tcpip, virtualización

Necesito mediante un script o puede ser un comando de vmware workstation 12 pro una instrucción la cual me entregue la dirección IP del SO montado en esta máquina virtual, que en este caso, es Windows XP.

Mi maquina host o anfitrion es Linux.

Esto lo quiero porque necesito que Conky me informe que ip tiene al proceder a ejecutar la maquina virtual, sin tener que entrar y colocar ipconfig, etc.

En realidad necesito un comando bash que me entregue la ip en definitiva.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes averiguar la mac que tiene tu máquina virtual (supongo que eso lo sabes hacer, si no, me lo dices y te indicamos) y luego una vez está en la red, desde tu anfitrión linux ejecuta `arp` que saca la lista de máquinas detectadas en la red con sus macs y le pasas un `grep` para quedarte solo la línea que interesa y `awk` para quedarte la ip que sea...

Ejemplo, supongamos que tu mac (la de tu XP virtual) es 00:11:22:33:44:55. Ejecutarías un comando `arp | grep 00:11:22:33:44:55 | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: No, anque la tengas en puente (bridged), la máquina virtual tiene una mac y la detectas igualmente. Puede que si tienes NAT tengas razón.

Comment: que raro... yo acabo de probarlo con una vm que tengo con Vmware y XP precisamente y sí me apareció. Bueno, ya nos dirá el que formuló la pregunta si le sirvió o no. :)

Comment: Pero si fuera configurada en NAT la ip ya la tienes, porque es la que tenga tu anfitrión asignada... todas las máquinas virtuales que usen ese interfaz van a tener la misma.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ha funcionado perfectamente. Perdón la demora. Lo ùnico malo es que arp no me la mostraba, pero fui a opciones avanzadas de VM-Settings-Hardware-Network Adapter-Advanced y genere una nueva MAC en el Vmware y aparecio la mascara y la ip en arp. Notar si que cuando tienen en /etc/hosts la ip puesta con un alias, arp muestra el alias, no la ip numérica. Tengo configurado en modo bridged sin replica.

Comment: para q no te resuelvas ips a nombres cambia en el comando `arp`por `arp -n`